# How to Check if Micro-USB Cable has a Short?

Tags: usb, short-circuit

Is there a way to test if my micro-USB cable has a short? I've got a multimeter.

I'm having problems programming an Atmel 328 AVR using USBASP with Avrdude, and I want to make sure that my cable is good.

Comment: Unless it is a cable you have made, I would highly doubt the cable is at fault. It might be worth posting some more information about your setup/connections with the ATMega and start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check a cable for shorts is to push a mating USB jack on one end of the cable. The jack will have the solder connections sticking out so that it is easy to check for shorts on the cable with your multimeter. The multimeter can be set for a low ohms range and then perform shorts checks including:

1. V+ to D-
2. V+ to D+
3. V+ to GND
4. D- to D+
5. D- to GND
6. D+ to GND

It is equally likely that the cable, if it is even possibly bad, to have an internal open circuit. In similar manner it is possible test this with a USB jack pushed onto both ends of the cable and then testing for continuity end to end:

7. V+ to V+
8. D- to D-
9. D+ to D+
10. GND to GND

Comment: The cable was messed up. I ordered a new one and it works fine.

Comment: @Laxmidi - Excellent!!